# Wie sagt man "Brandname" für Dinge in einem Lebensmittelgeschäft?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Wie sagt man "brandname" auf Deutsch? Wenn ich das Wort in einer Online-Übersetzung nachschlage, sagt sie "Marke". Ich möchte es in diesem Zusammenhang benützen:

> Ich werde morgen einige Hotdogs bei Raley's kaufen, aber ich weiß nicht, welche Hotdogs ich kaufen soll. Ich frage meine Frau, welche Marke der Hotdogs sie zum Frühstück haben möchte.

Passt das Wort "Marke" hier im Satz?

Comment: Ja. Obwohl die Vorstellung von Marken-Hotdogs komisch anmutet ... und dann auch noch zum Frühstück!

Comment: @Ingo... hier in Deutschland isst man halt eher Markenmüsli ;)

Comment: Echte Walddeutsche futtern zum Frühstück ein halbes Wildschwein, weder Müsli noch Hotdog. Ob Marke oder nicht ist dabei egal. Wieso traut man aber dem Wörterbuch nicht?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I would like to add that in this case you would probably (for having a more natural way of saying it) refer to

> Sorte von (kind of...) - Sorte von Hotdogs

I would consider saying

> Ich weiß nicht genau, welche Sorte der Hotdogs sie möchte...

as the most natural way of saying that.

**In addition, one "Marke" (brand or in this case producer) could have different "Sorten."**

Comment: The last sentence in bold is the most important bit here, I think :) (but lose the "in addition") To me, "Sorte" sounds more like talking about the *variety* rather than the *brand* of the hotdogs, i.e. whether they're pork, turkey or vegetarian... If the brand is in question, I think most Germans would simply leave out the "Sorte": "...welche Hotdogs sie möchte."

Comment: Sorte ist mit Chilie, vom Kalb und schlesische Art, aber nicht welche Marke. Die Antwort ist falsch.

Answer (score 11):

Ja, "Marke" passt. Allerdings klingt "Marke der Hotdogs" sehr umständlich. Natürlicher ist "Hotdogmarke" (vielleicht muss es auch "Hotdog-Marke" geschrieben werden, da bin ich nicht sicher).

Comment: Da "Hotdog" 3x in der Beispielkonstruktion vorkommt kann man sie ganz weglassen. Da mit Hotdogmarke kein Problem der Erfassung besteht würde ich es ordentlich zusammenschreiben.

Answer (score 1):

Umgangssprachlich könnte man noch fragen, ob sie "irgendwelche bestimmten" haben möchte.

Das schließt dann Marke, Hersteller *und* Sorte ein.